# make an exe file from a gui that runs another exe file

Tags: matlab, user-interface, deployment

I am trying to make an executable file from my GUI using deploytool.
I already did this work and all things was ok, but this time , in my GUI , I have a line similar to this: `dos(['Runner ' fileName])`; that Runner is an exe file.
I added all needed files and also Runner.exe to Shared Resources Files of deploytool.
now when I make an exe file from my GUI and run it , mentioned line of code does not run , that is Runner  does not run.

Comment: Add some debugging outputs. What does the dos output return? Is the exe placed in the directory where you call it? Check `ctfroot`.

Comment: @Daniel thank you, Runner must run another program and GUI must read output  of the program. but now , Runner does not run then mentioned program also does not  run and no output file created. then GUI could not read any data. in addition to Shared Resources Files and matlab root , I added Runner next to exe file of GUI but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Add the additional required file as an archive file.

Use the -a switch.

Compile the file from the command line.

So your command should look something like this:

mcc -m (yourfile.m) -a (the_additional_exe_file)

You can find more information here:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/mps/ml_code/mcc.html